# Prove that the median of this isosceles trapezoid is tangent to both circles.

Tags: geometry

[image]

What the problem really asks me to prove is that a circle can be inscribed in $ABCD$, or that $AB + CD = AC + BD$ or $2AB = AC + BD$ or $AB = \frac{AC+BD}{2} = PK$. I can do that **assuming** that $PK$ is tangent to both circles as shown in the picture and then apply the tangent-tangent theorem as needed, but

How can I prove that $PK$ is indeed tangent to both circles in the first place?
Could it be the secant to one of them?

By hand I find that the equality $AB = PK$ has to hold, but just after drawing the figure in Geogebra I realized that $PK$ is tangent to both circles. Otherwise I wouldn't been able to figure that out and wouldn't been able to complete the proof.

The fact that having to assume that $PK$ is tangent as if it were something found underneath a stone bugs me.

(In the original drawing, the only lines shown are $OB$, $OD$ and $OO_2$. The others, including $PK$ are my auxiliary constructions).

Comment: Next time you ask a question here, specify what all the assumptions are, e.g. here you should say that circle with center $O_1$ is tangent to lines at $A,C$, second one at $B,D$, that their tangency point is $M$ and that $PK$ is median line in the trapezoid. Even though it might be visible from the image, it might not be obvious to everyone.

Comment: @Wojowu (: If the problem would have been given as you suggest I wouldn't been that puzzled about $PK$ for so long. That $M$ is on $PK$ was a discovery made with a graph tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the line $l$ tangent to both circles at their tangency point. Suppose it intersects lines $OA$ and $OB$ at $K',P'$. Now $AK'=K'M=K'B$, so $K'$ is a midpoint of $AB$, so $K'=K$. Similarly $P'=P$, so line $l$ passes through $K,P$ so line $KP$ is tangent to both circles.